# Optimum Design Problems

Tags: math, matlab

I am stuck with a very simple question about minimizing an optimum design problem. 
Here is the question:

Minimize f(x,y) = (x-4)^2 + (y-6)^2 
subject to 12 >= x + y 
x >= 6, y>= 0

Comment: x=6,y=6 you can solve it closed form, without paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quadratic programming problem 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

fmincon is general nonlinear solver which can solve this kind of problem, however, quadprog is more suitable.

First of all, you should reformulate the problem into form
1/2 x'Qx+f'x
which is 
[x y][ 1 0; 0 1][x y]+ 2*[-4 -6][x; y]

then you can call quadprog function to get a result

```
xy = quadprog(eye(2),[-4 -6],[-1 0;0 -1 ; 1 1],[-6; 0;12])
```

For explanation, see

> help quadprog

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you in verifying your results:

This is the function in your region

[image]

Minimizing the function with Mathematica, give the obvious result:

```
Minimize[{f[x, y], 12 >= x + y, x >= 6, y >= 0}, {x, y}]
Out: {4, {x -> 6, y -> 6}}
```

HTH!